# Will my 300w PSU handle a Nvidia GeForce GTX 750 Ti?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I have an HP Compaq 800 Elite CMT Business PC. Will it be able to handle a Nvidia GeForce GTX 750 Ti?

My PC specs are:

- 4 GB of DDR3 RAM 1333MHz
- Intel Core 2 DUO E8400 3.0 GHz
- 300W PSU
- 250 GB HDD
- No graphics card

Answer (score 0):

This is within spec - just.  As the system is quite old I would stress test it after adding the card and be prepared to replace the PSU (older PSUs sometimes don't put out their rated power due to wear on componentry)

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU uses around 130W to 160W power according to [this benchmark article](http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleid=2394&page=2).

And as specified by nvidia in the [official GTX 750 Ti specifications](https://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti/specifications), you have the bare minimum of 300W PSU, as well as enough supply for your hardware, as that GPU uses around 60-70W of power. The hard drive and the RAM barely use any power, so it should be sufficient.